# Shape beside a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to recreate this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cplRL.png]

I've got the speech bubble finished, but I don't know how to position the blue dot exactly 50% of the height of the speech bubble (the speech bubble can vary in height) and 10px to the left of it.

Here's the JSFiddle I've started: [**http://jsfiddle.net/ghpCr/**](http://jsfiddle.net/ghpCr/)

HTML:

```
<div class="speech-bubble">
    Sample Text.
</div>

<div class="speech-bubble">
    Here's a <br /> bigger bubble.
</div>

<div class="dot"></div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.dot {
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background-color: #44769d;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.speech-bubble {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 18px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.speech-bubble:after, .speech-bubble:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.speech-bubble:before {
  border-color: rgba(204,204,204,0);
  border-right-color: #ccc;
  border-width: 9px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -9px;
}

.speech-bubble:after {
  border-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  border-right-color: #fff;
  border-width: 8px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

Comment: Are your shapes always going to be the same height?

Comment: No, the height of the bubble will differ.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to place the dot exactly outside on the left, this is achieved via `right: 100%;`. Next, you need to shift it a bit farther, hence `margin-right: 10px;`. Now for vertical alignment we use a similar method.

```
.dot {
    // ...
    right: 100%; 
    margin-right: 10px; 
    top: 50%; 
    margin-top: -6.5px;
}
```

Also note that the dot must be a child of the speech bubble. I posted this answer prior to the presence of actual markup.

Comment: @Hailwood Accounting for variable height would be impossible. Shapes just need another class if they have an alternate height by which `margin-top` could be adjusted to match it.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is undoubtedly the means of placing an element a fixed distance outside of another.

Comment: @stefan this was meant to communicate the methodology, not the entire source code. Of course you need to actually give it a color for it to show up... the full code would include `position: absolute;` (implicit given `right:...` and `top:...`) and all prior rules in his code.

Comment: @matt3141 could you link to a working jsFiddle with your code?

Comment: @stefan I certainly could. Do you see any flaw in my logic?

Comment: @matt3141 I don't but it would be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to put the group in a container, so you can easily control the position of each element inside of that container together.

```
<div class="speech-bubble-container">
     <div class="dot"></div>
     <div class="speech-bubble">
         Here's a <br /> bigger bubble.<br/>    
     </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ghpCr/4/

Comment: Unnecessary. The overhead of markup is kept down by placing the dot within the bubble.

Comment: Are we really calling a single DIV expensive?

Comment: Heck we might as well use `:before` and get rid of the `.dot` altogether!

Comment: :before is already being used to contruct the arrows. While adding it will render the circle, it binds the circle to the arrow, not allowing for a horizontial margin between the two.  The arrow ends up overlapping the circle with no way to move it.

Comment: `:after` works just as well although no longer semantic. That was sarcasm, too.

Comment: Is there a way to make it without a container, so that the dot can be positioned anywhere on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use display table, try this :

<kbd>**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/V24dT/show)**</kbd>

## HTML

```
<div class="level1">
 <div class="level2">
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="speech-bubble">
    Sample Text.
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

## css

```
.level1 {
    display: table-row;
}
.level2 {
    display: table-cell;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.dot {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    background-color: #44769d;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position:absolute;
    top:42%; /* or use top:50%;margin-top:-6.5px; */
    left:2%;
}

.speech-bubble {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.speech-bubble:after, .speech-bubble:before {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid transparent;
    content:"";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.speech-bubble:before {
    border-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0);
    border-right-color: #ccc;
    border-width: 9px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -9px;
}
.speech-bubble:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-right-color: #fff;
    border-width: 8px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
```